# Tikz: Horizontal alignment to another node than direct parent

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to reassmble this tree structure:

[image]

How can I position the "Minus" node on the fourth level to the root and set the edge length accordingly?

My MWE so far:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,node distance=2cm]
        \node (first) {$+$};
        \node[below left of=first] (secondLeft) {$+$};
        \node[below right of=first] (secondRight) {$\cdot$};
        
        \node[below right of=secondLeft] (thirdLeft) {$\cdot$};
        \node[below right of=secondRight] (thirdRight) {$d$};
        
        \node[below left of=thirdLeft] (fourthLeft) {$a$};
        \node[below right of=thirdLeft] (fourthRight) {$-$};
        
        \node[below left of=fourthRight] (fifthLeft) {$b$};
        \node[below right of=fourthRight] (fifthRight) {$c$};
        
        \draw (first) -- (secondLeft);
        \draw (first) -- (secondRight);
        
        \draw (secondLeft) -- (thirdLeft);
        \draw (secondRight) -- (thirdRight);
        \draw (secondRight) -- (fourthRight);
        
        \draw (thirdLeft) -- (fourthLeft);
        \draw (thirdLeft) -- (fourthRight);
        
        \draw (fourthRight) -- (fifthLeft);
        \draw (fourthRight) -- (fifthRight);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I feel like I'm looking for an option like "below right of thirdRight and below of first" or something like that.

Comment: You could add `node distance=4cm` as option to `(secondLeft)` and `(secondRight)` (and something like `yshift=1cm` if you feel that the vertical distance is too large).

Comment: Thank you, did it like this and worked.

Comment: If you load the [`positioning` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) you can do `below=of thirdLeft -| first` where `thirdLeft -| first` denotes a points that lies on the intersection between a horizontal through thirdLeft and a vertical of first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to load the [`positioning` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) (→ [manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.positioning)) and use the appropriate keys:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1cm, on grid, math nodes]
\node                                (P0) {+};
\node[below  left=1cm and 2cm of P0] (P1) {+};
\node[below right=1cm and 2cm of P0] (M0) {\cdot};
\node[below right=            of P1] (M1) {\cdot};
\node[below right=            of M1] (m0) {-};
\node[below  left=            of M1] (a)  {a};
\node[below  left=            of m0] (b)  {b};
\node[below right=            of m0] (c)  {c};
\node[below right=            of M0] (d)  {d};

\path (P0) edge (P1) edge (M0)
      (P1) edge (M1) edge[bend right] (a)
      (M0) edge (m0) edge (d)
      (M1) edge (m0) edge (a)
      (m0) edge (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice how I've used `1cm and 2cm` with `P1` and `M0`? This is double the horizontal space but the same vertical distance compared to the default node distance `1cm and 1cm`.
When the `ext.positioning-plus` is loaded, one can use

```
\node[below  left=1 and 2:of P0] (P1) {+};
\node[below right=1 and 2:of P0] (M0) {\cdot};
```

where the part before the `:` denotes a factor the default node distance should be multiplied with. This allows you to later change the default `node distance` in the options of the TikZ picture without having to go through all nodes and correct the hard-coded distances yourself.

I always add `text depth = 0pt` and `text height = .7em` so that the nodes are aligned better.

---

That said, I think you're better off placing the nodes in a matrix. The `tikzcd` package loaded with the `cd` library makes this very convenient.

```
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small, arrows=dash]
 & & +         \ar[dll] \ar[drr]           \\
+              \ar[dr] \ar[dd, bend right]
 & & & & \cdot \ar[dr] \ar[ddll]           \\
 & \cdot       \ar[dl] \ar[dr]
   & & & & d                              \\
a  & & -       \ar[dl] \ar[dr]             \\
 & b
   & & c
\end{tikzcd}
```

This way, your diagram is built like a `tabular` or an `array`. The `\ar` macro is used to place the edges between the nodes. It accepts the same options as a [`to` path](https://tikz.dev/library-edges) like `bend right`. With the keys `d`, `l`, `u` and `r` you specify the target node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, positioning, ext.positioning-plus}
\tikzset{math nodes/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=small, arrows=dash]
 & & +         \ar[dll] \ar[drr]           \\
+              \ar[dr] \ar[dd, bend right]
 & & & & \cdot \ar[dr] \ar[ddll]           \\
 & \cdot       \ar[dl] \ar[dr]
   & & & & d                              \\
a  & & -       \ar[dl] \ar[dr]             \\
 & b
   & & c
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm, on grid, math nodes,
  text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em]
\node                                (P0) {+};
\node[below  left=1cm and 2cm of P0] (P1) {+};
\node[below right=1cm and 2cm of P0] (M0) {\cdot};
\node[below right=            of P1] (M1) {\cdot};
\node[below right=            of M1] (m0) {-};
\node[below  left=            of M1] (a)  {a};
\node[below  left=            of m0] (b)  {b};
\node[below right=            of m0] (c)  {c};
\node[below right=            of M0] (d)  {d};

\path (P0) edge (P1) edge (M0)
      (P1) edge (M1) edge[bend right] (a)
      (M0) edge (m0) edge (d)
      (M1) edge (m0) edge (a)
      (m0) edge (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=8mm and 8mm, on grid, math nodes,
  text depth=+0pt, text height=+.7em]
\node                            (P0) {+};
\node[below  left=1 and 2:of P0] (P1) {+};
\node[below right=1 and 2:of P0] (M0) {\cdot};
\node[below right=        of P1] (M1) {\cdot};
\node[below right=        of M1] (m0) {-};
\node[below  left=        of M1] (a)  {a};
\node[below  left=        of m0] (b)  {b};
\node[below right=        of m0] (c)  {c};
\node[below right=        of M0] (d)  {d};

\path (P0) edge (P1) edge (M0)
      (P1) edge (M1) edge[bend right] (a)
      (M0) edge (m0) edge (d)
      (M1) edge (m0) edge (a)
      (m0) edge (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

(They're all relatively the same.)

[image]